# PHP | Minecraft Offline UUID

Tags: php, uuid, minecraft

i am creating a user control panel for a minecraft server, and if a client click "buy now" button, update in the database (permissionex(a ranksystem plugin)) client's rank. permission ex is indetify by minecraft offline UUID.

minecraft uuid: md5("OfflinePlayer:" + name) BUT
this and the database uuid, 2 letters difference.

my database uuid: 7a1a45e593cc389007345468dd059e70

my website's uuid: 7a1a45e593cc389087345468dd059e70

thank you and sorry for my bad english

my code:

```
$offlineuuid = md5("OfflinePlayer:".$_SESSION['username']."");

$uuid = MojangAPI::formatUuid($offlineuuid); // Egy API-t felhasználva át alakítja teljes UUID-vé (kötőjelessé)
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "rank");

echo "".$uuid."<br>"; // <-- a SESSION uuidje (a név amivel belépett a weboldalra)


$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "rank");

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM permissions_inheritance WHERE child='$uuid'");
echo "7a1a45e5-93cc-3890-8734-5468dd059e70<br>";  //<- adatbázis UUIDje
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

I only see one digit different between the two UUIDs in your question: in the "variant" field. Your "database" UUID has a value of 0xxx, which is reserved for backward compatibility with a long-obeolete system and is almost certainly invalid. Your "website" UUID has a value of 10xx, which is for RFC4122 and nearly always correct.

In short: you are not generating your UUID correctly and one piece of software is trying to (somewhat) fix it for you and the other isn't. The solution is to generate a valid UUID that both will accept.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

Example use:
`$uuid = offlinePlayerUuid("HereThePlayerName123");`

Put into your code:

```
function offlinePlayerUuid($username) {
    //extracted from the java code:
    //new GameProfile(UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(("OfflinePlayer:" + name).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)), name));
    $data = hex2bin(md5("OfflinePlayer:" . $username));
    //set the version to 3 -> Name based md5 hash
    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x30);
    //IETF variant
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80);
    return createJavaUuid(bin2hex($data));
}

function createJavaUuid($striped) {
    //example: 069a79f4-44e9-4726-a5be-fca90e38aaf5
    $components = array(
        substr($striped, 0, 8),
        substr($striped, 8, 4),
        substr($striped, 12, 4),
        substr($striped, 16, 4),
        substr($striped, 20),
    );
    return implode('-', $components);
}
```